# Get values submitted to php from form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Consider the following form:

```
<form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="foo">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="foo">
</form>
```

When submitting the form, the URL `...?foo=0` will be requested if the checkbox is not checked. If the checkbox is checked, the URL `...?foo=0&foo=1` will be requested. In PHP, query string arguments override any previous arguments with the same name, so `foo` will have the value `1` in the PHP script handling the latter request.

What is the best way to obtain the value `foo` would have in the PHP script using JavaScript, when not knowing anything about the form? In theory, there could be an arbitrary number of inputs named `foo` of different types, and I would like to know the value that `foo` would have in the PHP script handling the request if the form was submitted.

As I understand it, the answer is the value of the last enabled input element named `foo`. By enabled, I mean that the input element is not disabled and that it is not a button (the button's name and value are not added to the query string unless the button is used to submit the form) or an unchecked checkbox or radio button.

Maybe there is an easy way to get this value using jQuery?

**Edit**

Loads of people suggest that I rename the input elements to `foo[]` or similar. I guess I was not clear enough that I actually want all the input elements named `foo`, and to only receive one of the values in the php script.

My questions is how to determine which value the php script will receive using JavaScript.

Comment: Why your inputs have same name ? Change foo1 and foo2.

Comment: have you tried by setting an array as name ? (`name="foo[]"`)

Comment: I only want to keep the last enabled `foo`, so they should all be named `foo`.

Comment: Good luck with keeping all same names.....makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop on the global variable $_GET

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$val) {
   echo "key = $key , val = $val";
}
```

if you have multiple inputs with the same name you will need to append `[]`to the name so you can get all the values as a array

```
<form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="foo[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="foo[]">
</form>
```

to get the values in jquery you do the following:

```
$('input[name="foo[]"]').each(function(){
 console.log($(this).val());
});
```

if you only want one value of foo but you have multiple elements with that name you will need to change your logic to using radio buttons

Comment: I want to determine the value using JavaScript, without submitting the form.

Comment: change your name attributes to array as name="foo[the_variable_name]", then in php, you can easily get it via one variable

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="foo[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="foo[]">
</form>
```

and in PHP, use:

```
$params = $_GET['foo']; //params would hold array
```

it would be good to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad design. You should check checkbox state in your php (backend) code. Get rid of the hidden input:

```
<form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="foo">
</form>
```

and put this in your php code:

```
if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
  $foo = 1;
} else {
  $foo = 0;
}
```

If you want to use javascript, you can try this on form submit:

```
var checkboxValue = $("input[name='foo']").prop("checked");
```

**checkboxValue** would be true or false depending on checkbox status.